# Ceiling fans falling

Tags: ceiling-fan

I've had this problem with multiple Harbor Breeze fans in the house we bought. Each bedroom has a ceiling fan where the rod terminates in a half-ball (pretty typical). The half-ball is hung from a bracket that, presumably came with the fan. In multiple cases, this bracket appears to have expanded, causing the ceiling fan to fall. So far, nobody has been hurt but it's clearly a concern.

I picked up a new bracket (#0033976) from Lowe's and the new bracket is about 1/4" tighter than the old one. This will address the short term problem but I'm concerned that 10 years from now the new one will stretch and fans will fall again.

The old bracket is metal so it's not the case that plastic has stretched.

Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the problem/expanded bracket?  Your state/province/region/country should have a local consumer product safety office.  If this is happening to multiple units of the same maker, they will most likely want to know about it.  Spinning fans that fall do not sound like a safe place to be around.   I would probably replace all those fans with another product/maker.

Comment: I found the customer service # on the fan (Lowe's related). Called them.  They are give me a song and dance about it being an older fan and that it might have been installed with the wrong parts (unlikely).

Comment: A consumer product safety office/department is government.  Hopefully your government cares enough about you.  Customer service is just a company number to maybe help you find parts to buy or to find where to send parts for expensive repair.  Seeing the pic, there does seem to be a defect.

Comment: Are you sure that both side were securely mounted? The right-hand side in your pic seems to have bent upwards in a way which it wouldn't have been able to do if it were screwed onto a flat surface, or am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: Also - check the installation instructions for your fans & for your new bracket. I'm almost certain that they'll tell you to screw the bracket to a fan-rated outlet box, and not directly to a ceiling joist ...

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to use a box. The electrical runs are terrible, wires not attached anywhere, draped on suspended ceiling, etc. The whole floor needs to be redone but I'm partway through replumbing the whole house to replace CPVC with PEX-A due to a leak and my wife says "I want water working before you do the electrical". Yes, it was solidly attached to the joist - I think the metal was just so weak that over time it bent. The new bracket seems stronger, I guess I'll just go with that.

Comment: And a Hubbell-Raco 295 pancake box.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Harbor breeze fan bracket wore out and the fan fell. If was 12yrs old but worked fine. It was installed properly to an outlet box, but over time the metal fan bracket bent enough just like your picture. I ordered a replacement bracket and this time wrapped it with a hanger strap. Luckily it fell on the bed so it still works.

[image]